# Justify adjoining roots of unity to solve a polynomial by radicals

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

Specifically, I've been reading a standard procedure to solve a general cubic polynomial by taking field extensions by radicals.

As part of the procedure, a cube root $\omega$ of unity is adjoined. At first, this step seemed fine to me because it is all about adjoining radicals. But then I started thinking about how the mathematicians in the 1500's posed the problem. Take the coefficients of a polynomial, and then use arithmetic operations and root extraction to provide a formula to solve the polynomial. Adjoining a cube root $\omega$ for a field extension seems to provide extra support, above and beyond what is "allowed" to solve a polynomial.

Justify adjoining roots of unity to solve a polynomial by radicals. That is, show that solving a polynomial by taking field extensions by radicals, including roots of unity, still leads to an explicit formula using arithmetic operations and root extraction on the coefficients.

Comment: You have suggested a historical view as motivating the Question, but this doesn't seem fully consistent with what is described as "a standard procedure to solve a general cubic polynomial."  Before I'd attempt to write an explanation to "[j]ustify adjoining roots of unity", some clarity about whether a historical account or a modern argument is sought.

Comment: Other than allowing complex numbers, the procedure using field extensions by radicals to solve a general cubic polynomial I can see aims to answer the same question historically, and I can see a formula that can get generated, except I need clarification on adjoining a root of unity, which seem to provide additional help, not directly connected to the coefficients.

Comment: The modern statements of solvability by radicals do not say anything about "solvable by radicals depending somehow on the coefficients". After all, how will you make precise "directly connected to the coefficients"? Since a root of unity is a sort of radical, it seems highly reasonable to allow their use in solving an equation by radicals.

Comment: If you have a question about understanding some write-up that you found online, it would be helpful to provide a link to that; otherwise the citation of author and document would serve much the same purpose.  Once one accepts the complex number system, there turns out to be nothing more that needs "adjoining".  The roots of unity are after all easily computed complex numbers.  How they are used in "a standard procedure to solve a general cubic polynomial" might well be worth exposition, but without further context the coefficients of that polynomial might be arbitrary complex numbers.

Comment: I've been reading A Course in Galois Theory by Garling, specifically 14.3 Cubic Polynomials, and I think it is a standard treatment of extension by radicals to capture the roots of a general cubic polynomial. Steps are to adjoin the square root of the discriminant, then cube root of unity, and then two cube roots (expressed using the cube root of unity). I guess I'm now accepting that roots of unity are allowed in the process. And [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html) in (55) and (56), I see that the explicit formulas have not just the coefficients but also $\omega$.

Comment: Actually, now that I'm thinking about $x^n - 2$, the roots of unity seem like a natural part of the process.

Comment: If you think also about $x^n - 1$ you will see roots of unity are very much a part of solving by radicals.